# How to automatically save a file using react-pdf

Tags: reactjs, pdf, react-pdf, react-pdfrenderer

Good evening everybody
I'm creating a react app (to embed into a WordPress site, just in case you need this info) that gets some data from a form and than create a pdf file, via react-pdf module ( https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf )

To make react-pdf compatible with React 18.2.0, I added a couple of lines to my package.json file, as suggested here (https://gist.github.com/gitname/bdc1fb7fe5bd0c22f6656b7905f57cd6 ):

```
"overrides": {
  "@react-pdf/renderer": {
    "react": "^18.2.0"
  }
 },
```

This file must be stored somewhere in the server, without giving any consent message to the user.

I tried using usePDF hook ( https://react-pdf.org/hooks )to get the instance.blob content, but now I don't know how to store it.

```
import React from "react";
import { usePDF, Page, Text, View, Document, StyleSheet } from "@react-pdf/renderer";

// Create styles
const styles = StyleSheet.create({ ... something ...});

// Create Document Component
const MyDocument = () => (
  <Document>
    <Page size="A4" style={styles.page}>
      <View style={styles.section}>
        <Text>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque, reprehenderit! 
        </Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.section}>
        <Text>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
        </Text>
      </View>
    </Page>
  </Document>
);

const MyPdfComponent = () => {
  const [instance, updateInstance] = usePDF({ document: <MyDocument /> });
 
  if (instance.loading) return <div>Loading ...</div>;
 
  if (instance.error) return <div>Something went wrong: {instance.error}</div>;

  if (instance.blob) {
    /* What can I put here? */

    return <div>PDF have been generated...</div>;
  }
};

export default MyPdfComponent;
```

According to the official docs, I first tried using this code:

```
import ReactPDF from '@react-pdf/renderer';
ReactPDF.render(<MyDocument />, `${__dirname}/example.pdf`);
```

But something goes wrong, because I have a message telling me that **"render is a Node specific API. You're either using this method in a browser, or your bundler is not loading react-pdf from the appropriate web build."**

I just need that the file is programmatically stored in a specific folder and the user is redirected to a success page (or something I have to implement...)

Any hint for that?

Tank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Next.JS, you have to render this component only on the client, the hook usePDF only works client side.

You will have to import the component like so:

```js
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

const MyDocument = dynamic(async () => {
  const m = await import("path/to/MyDocument");

  // if no default export
  return m.MyDocument;

  // if default export
  return m.default;
},{ ssr:false });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yow will need a package the allows you to save the file. "react-pdf" generates the pdf and "file-saver" allows you to download it.

See example code:

```
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';
import { Page, Text, View, Document, StyleSheet, pdf } from '@react-pdf/renderer';

function savePDF() {
  try {
    const doc = (
      <Document>
        <Page>
          <Text>Hello, World!</Text>
        </Page>
      </Document>
    );

    const asPdf = pdf([]); // {} is important, throws without an argument
    asPdf.updateContainer(doc);
    const pdfBlob = asPdf.toBlob();
    saveAs(pdfBlob, 'document.pdf');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    alert('Error generating PDF');
  }
}

function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={savePDF}>Save PDF</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyComponent;
```

There is another more advanced version for larger file called "streamsaver". But file-saver should work well for your intended purpose.

You can also use custom stylesheet to style your text and views.